# Status 0 on uploading image with Rails and Backblaze B2 (S3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, cloud-storage, backblaze

When I try to upload a photo on my Rails app I get this error "Error storing "image.jpg" Status: 0" I am using ActiveStorage with Backblaze B2 which is based on Amazon S3. I have setup the bucket already.

I have tried changing regions but nothing happend.

This is in my storage.yml:

```
backblaze:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: keyID from my account
    secret_access_key: master key from my account
    region: us-east-1
    bucket: my bucketID
    endpoint: b2 upload url I got from b2_get_upload_url
    force_path_style: true
```

I have set `config.active_storage.service = :backblaze` in both development and production environments.

This is code for file input in my form:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, direct_upload: true, multiple: false %>
```

I want to see image I posted in my file browser in my bucket but it is not uploading.

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Status 0 (from my experience) relates to a failure to do with CORS. We use Azure as our storage platform (with Rails / ActiveStorage) and the root cause was the blob container not having a CORS policy configured. I'm not sure how this works with Backblaze, but if you configure a CORS policy and add the domain that you have your rails app on (with PUT/POST enabled), that should help